# Mutt configuration for davmail connected to ms exchange

Tags: email, exchange, mutt

I have davmail setup to fetch/send email from ms exchange server. The setup works with Thunderbird properly.

I want to configure mutt to work with it instead as thunderbird is very resource savvy.

I tried to configure as per simple imap account, but I always get login failed message from davmail, at the same time Thunderbird works with the same credentials

Comment: Which version of mutt and what muttrc options have you set to configure IMAP?

Comment: I have mutt 1.5.21 under Archlinux

Comment: Have you resolved this since?